# C++11 static struct in class compiles, why won't it link?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to provide a one-time configuration of a number of objects.

This code:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    static struct Bar {
      bool a = true;
      int b = 69;
    } bar;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Foo::bar.a = false;
}
```

compiles just fine:

```
$ g++ -c -std=gnu++11 main.cpp
```

but the linker complains of missing symbols:

```
$ g++ main.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Foo::bar", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why doesn't this work?

and

What is a better way of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable is only *declared* inside the class definition, so you need a *(single) definition* of this static variable, as for any other static variable:

```
Foo::Bar Foo::bar;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e330697f1e4308b5). Remember there can only be one of these definitions in your whole binary (be it a library or executable), so this definition cannot be in a header that can be included from several translation units (*i.e.* source files).

Comment: Ah! I thought the brace-or-equal-initializers would do that. I'll accept as soon as...you bet the accept timer.

Comment: @helpwithhaskell you only initialize the data members of the inner class, never of the static class member `bar`. So any code such as: `Foo::Bar b;` will have `b`'s data members initialized to the values you provided, this would be a definition of the variable `b`, just like the above `Foo::Bar Foo::bar` is a definition of the (static member) variable `bar` of Foo.